# binary search tree assignment operator

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am having a huge issue with my recursive function in my binary search tree. My project is due in a few hours and I cannot for the life of me get ahold of my instructor.

My function seems to only be traversing the left most branch of my tree.

Assignment Operator:

```
template<typename Type>
BST<Type>& BST<Type>::operator=(const BST& that)
{
    if(this != &that)
    {
        this->clear();
        Node *c = that.root;
        preORet(c);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Recursive Function Called:

```
template<typename Type>
void BST<Type>::preORet(Node *c)
{
    this->insert(c->data);

    if(c->left != nullptr)
        preORet(c->left);
    else if(c->right != nullptr)
        preORet(c->right);
}
```

As an aside, I understand that a lot of this may look like seriously bastardized code, but this is how my instructor expects it to look.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
if(c->left != nullptr)
    preORet(c->left);
else if(c->right != nullptr)
    preORet(c->right);
```

You don't want an `else if`. You want to traverse the right sub-tree regardless of whether the left sub-tree was a nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to taking out the `else` in your `preORet()` function, as the others have pointed out, it's also worth noting that you will get a segmentation fault (error code 11) if you happen to pass in a null pointer through your parameter `Node *c`.

Here is a solution:

```
template<typename Type>
void BST<Type>::preORet(Node *c)
{
    if (c != nullptr)
    {
        this->insert(c->data);
        preORet(c->left);
        preORet(c->right);
    }
}
```

This way, every pointer get's checked to see if it is null before being used, including the left and right pointers. If it is null, it'll just fall through, out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the else in preORet().

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that `else`.

As your design looks, at first glance, to be easily `move` or `swap` able, I would use the copy-`swap` idiom to generate a reasonably efficient, easy to write `operator=`.

But that is just me.